# Calculating entanglement with CRZ Gates on non-neighbor qubits

Tags: quantum-state, entanglement, quantum-circuit, linear-algebra

I'm trying to prove that my quantum circuit is behaving the way I want it to, which means I want to calculate its state vector. Until entanglement, I can show it works using the bloch-sphere - after entanglement that option is gone, so I have to go back to good 'ol maths.

This is my circuit (Simplified and made smaller to easen up initial calculations):
[image: Simple 3 qubit circuit with an RY layer, as well as selected CRZ entanglement]

So these are the steps I have so far:

Initial state
$$
q_0 =\ q_1 =\ q_2 =\ |0\rangle\\
$$

State after RY-Gate
$$
q_0 =\ q_1 =\ q_2 =\ RY(c_i)|0\rangle =\ \begin{pmatrix}
        \cos{\frac{c_i}{2}} & -\sin{\frac{c_i}{2}} \\
        \sin{\frac{c_i}{2}} & \cos{\frac{c_i}{2}}
    \end{pmatrix}|0\rangle =\ \begin{pmatrix}
        \cos{\frac{c_i}{2}}\\
        \sin{\frac{c_i}{2}}\\
    \end{pmatrix}\\
$$

Now before applying the CRZ-Gates we create the tensor product of all qubits

$$
q_2 \otimes q_1 \otimes q_0 =\ \begin{pmatrix}
     \cos{\frac{c0}{2}}\cos{\frac{c1}{2}}\cos{\frac{c2}{2}}\\
     \cos{\frac{c1}{2}}\cos{\frac{c2}{2}}\sin{\frac{c0}{2}}\\
     \cos{\frac{c0}{2}}\cos{\frac{c2}{2}}\sin{\frac{c1}{2}}\\
     \cos{\frac{c2}{2}}\sin{\frac{c0}{2}}\sin{\frac{c1}{2}}\\
     \cos{\frac{c0}{2}}\cos{\frac{c1}{2}}\sin{\frac{c2}{2}}\\
     \cos{\frac{c1}{2}}\sin{\frac{c0}{2}}\sin{\frac{c2}{2}}\\
     \cos{\frac{c0}{2}}\sin{\frac{c1}{2}}\sin{\frac{c2}{2}}\\
     \sin{\frac{c0}{2}}\sin{\frac{c1}{2}}\sin{\frac{c2}{2}}\\
     \end{pmatrix}
$$

The CRZ Gate for `s02` has to match the size of the tensor product, but only apply to the qubit 0 and 2. Standard CRZ gate
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & e^{-i\frac{\lambda}{2}} & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & e^{i\frac{\lambda}{2}}
    \end{pmatrix}
$$

Now we make it 8x8 in size.
$$
CRZ^{8\times 8}_{q_0,q_2} =\ \begin{pmatrix}
     1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
     0 & e^{-i\frac{\lambda}{2}} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
     0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
     0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
     0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
     0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
     0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
     0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & e^{i\frac{\lambda}{2}}\\
     \end{pmatrix}
$$

Now, the $CRZ^{8\times 8}_{q_0,q_2}$ gate is something I think is correct? I get the tensor product of all qubits, and then I change the $CRZ$ gate so that it can be used to calculate, but does not touch the state of $q_1$. To be completely honest, I don't know if this works, or is the right approach. Until now, I only calculated entanglement in circular fashion of neighbouring qubits, which is straightforward, but I somehow can't even find much literature on this, which might also be because I'm using the wrong formalism.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than constructing large matrices, you can continue using bra-ket notation with an outer-product representation for the operators. So your standard controlled-Z gate acting on target and control qubits $q_0$ and $q_1$ respectively would be:
$$
|00\rangle\langle00|\otimes I + 
|1\rangle\langle 1| \otimes 
\big( e^{-\iota \lambda/2}|0\rangle\langle0| + e^{\iota \lambda/2}|1\rangle\langle1| \big)
$$
(refer qiskit [docs](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.circuit.library.CRZGate.html))

Here the term that is being tensored with $|1\rangle\langle1|$ is the Rotation-Z Gate.
Hope this gave you a different and a neater formalism to continue your understanding of the circuit that you have constructed :)

Comment: Thanks for the input, I know that notation but thought it would make things simpler if I used matrices, which seemingly was wrong :)

Comment: What would I have to change for it to be $q_0$ and $q_2$? That's my current problem I can't seem to figure out, nor find any details on.

Comment: Since you can't ignore `q_1` from the circuit, you will have to add an Identity operation for the same.